# Exception when updating entities bound to dataGrid in wpf entity framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, xaml, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have two entities: (Entity Framework code first approach)

```
public class Work
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        Works = new ObservableCollection<Work>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Work> Works { get; private set; }
}
```

And I have the following XAML: (DataGrid Work item)
(I want to display a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` which would contain all Department names)

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idColumn5" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Width="100"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="titleColumn2" Binding="{Binding Title}" Header="Title" Width="250"/>   

                                <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Department.Name, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                    NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"  Header="Department Name"
                                                   ItemsSource="{x:Static my:MainWindow.Departments}"
                                                        DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID"
                                                    Width="140"/>

                                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="priceColumn2" Binding="{Binding Price}" Header="Price" Width="90"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

VS 2012 outlines (error) the `ItemsSource="{x:Static my:MainWindow.Departments}"`:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.Departments'.
```

But I can start the project.

When I'm trying to add new Work I get (inner inner exception):

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Works_dbo.Departments_DepartmentId". The conflict occurred in
>   database "MyDbName", table "dbo.Departments", column 'id'.

Also I have this property in MainWindow object:

```
    public static ICollection<Department> Departments
    {
        get
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName == "devenv")
                return new List<Department>();
            return _context.Departments.ToList();
        }
    }
```

I'm new to WPF and this type of data binding and XAML too.
Will appretiate any answer that can help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just needed to change `Binding Path=` from `Department.Name` to `DepartmentId` )